# why aren't we finding more off spinners who can bowl a doosra as well

Tags: cricket, spin

Nowadays we see wrist spinners bowling leg spin and googly and they are very successful. But we do not see a finger spinner bowling off spin and doosra at the same time.why is the game of cricket not producing finger spinner who bowls doosra as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nowadays we see wrist spinners bowling leg spin and googly and they are very successful.

The googly isn't really a "nowadays" thing - [it was first bowled in 1900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Bosanquet_(cricketer)#Genesis) and has been part of just about every top-class wrist spinner's arsenal since then.

> But we do not see a finger spinner bowling off spin and doosra at the same time

Yes, we do. To take a very recent example, [Akila Dananjaya](http://www.espncricinfo.com/srilanka/content/player/574178.html) who played in the first two Tests of the 2018-19 Sri Lanka vs England series is described by Cricinfo as:

> Able to deliver a [...] doosra and a stock offspinner with astounding control

To answer your last point:

> why is the game of cricket not producing finger spinner who bowls doosra as well.

Because the doosra is very hard, some would same impossible, to bowl legally, that is without flexing the arm more than 15 degrees. Offspinners, in particularly "unorthodox" offspinners, have taken the brunt of the ICC crackdown on illegal bowling actions in recent years; Dananjaya will not be playing in the third test of the Sri Lanka - England series as will be undergoing an assessment of his bowling action.

Comment: i was not saying that leg spinner is a nowadays thing it was just the build up and was trying to say that they are very much more successful than off spinners second part that you considered was not a particular bowler i said "off spinner's" so i wanted more examples of off spinners bowling doosra as well and you answered the third part of the question very well